# How to check if a folder exist or not in Azure container using Python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a storage container and inside that I have 3 levels of directories as follow:

```
--Container
  --Folder1
    --Folder2
      --Folder3
        --blobs here
```

I need to check are there any blob present in Folder3 or even better just check if Folder3 exist or not.
I tried to use 
`blob_exist = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str = os.getenv("conString"), container_name="Container",blob_name="Folder1/Folder2/Folder3").exists()`

It always returns **False** irrespective of folder exists or not. Can anybody tell me how can I achieve this?
I know empty folders doesn't exist in Blob Containers, but my intension is to check if a folder exists, then continue other business logic.

Comment: Will os.walk() work for you?  Refer to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm

Comment: Can you solve the issue by the answer below? if it helps, could you please accept it as answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible to directly check if a folder exists in blob storage. But you can use the `list_blobs()` method and the `name_starts_with` parameter.

For example:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

blob_service_client=BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connstr)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container)
myblobs = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with="Folder1/Folder2/Folder3")

#define a list to store the blobs if exists
blob_list=[]

for s in myblobs:
    blob_list.append(s)
    #use break to make sure only one iteration to avoid iterating all the blobs
    break

if len(blob_list) > 0:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: Thank you @Ivan Yang for the solution. It served my purpose.

Comment: im using this now, thank you

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
import os
def myfind( folder, container):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(container, topdown=False):
        if folder in dirs: return True
    return False

myfind('Folder3
```